# reduced density matrix for the given composite system

Tags: linear-algebra, tensor-products, operator-algebras, quantum-mechanics

Given the composite system of two qubits

$$
|\psi^{AB}\rangle=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}(|0^{A}\rangle \otimes|0^{B}\rangle+|1^{A}\rangle\otimes|1^{B}\rangle)
$$
with the density matrix of the composite system 
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\rho^{AB}=|\psi^{AB}\rangle\langle\psi^{AB}|=\frac{1}{2}[{|0^{A}\rangle \otimes|0^{B}\rangle\langle0^{A}|\otimes\langle0^{B}|+|1^{A}\rangle \otimes|1^{B}\rangle\langle0^{A}|\otimes\langle0^{B}|+|0^{A}\rangle \otimes|0^{B}\rangle\langle1^{A}|\otimes\langle1^{B}|+|1^{A}\rangle \otimes|1^{B}\rangle\langle1^{A}|\otimes\langle1^{B}|}]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
The reduced density operator of $A$, i.e,  $\rho^{A}$ is

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\rho^{A}=\text{tr}_{B}(\rho^{AB})=\langle0^{B}|\rho^{AB}|0^{B}\rangle+\langle1^{B}|\rho^{AB}|1^{B}\rangle=\frac{1}{2}[{\langle0^{B}|0^{A}\rangle \otimes|0^{B}\rangle\langle0^{A}|\otimes\langle0^{B}|0^{B}\rangle+\langle0^{B}|1^{A}\rangle \otimes|1^{B}\rangle\langle0^{A}|\otimes\langle0^{B}|0^{B}\rangle+\langle0^{B}|0^{A}\rangle \otimes|0^{B}\rangle\langle1^{A}|\otimes\langle1^{B}|0^{B}\rangle+\langle0^{B}|1^{A}\rangle \otimes|1^{B}\rangle\langle1^{A}|\otimes\langle1^{B}|0^{B}\rangle}+{\langle1^{B}|0^{A}\rangle \otimes|0^{B}\rangle\langle0^{A}|\otimes\langle0^{B}|1^{B}\rangle+\langle1^{B}|1^{A}\rangle \otimes|1^{B}\rangle\langle0^{A}|\otimes\langle0^{B}|1^{B}\rangle+\langle1^{B}|0^{A}\rangle \otimes|0^{B}\rangle\langle1^{A}|\otimes\langle1^{B}|1^{B}\rangle+\langle1^{B}|1^{A}\rangle \otimes|1^{B}\rangle\langle1^{A}|\otimes\langle1^{B}|1^{B}\rangle}]\\ =\frac{1}{2}[\langle0^{B}|0^{A}\rangle \otimes|0^{B}\rangle\langle0^{A}|\otimes I_{B}+\langle0^{B}|1^{A}\rangle \otimes|1^{B}\rangle\langle0^{A}|\otimes I_{B}+\langle1^{B}|0^{A}\rangle \otimes|0^{B}\rangle\langle1^{A}|\otimes I_{B}+\langle1^{B}|1^{A}\rangle \otimes|1^{B}\rangle\langle1^{A}|\otimes I_{B}]
\end{split}
\end{equation}
I think the expansion is correct so far.

How do I proceed further and prove that $\rho^{A}=\frac{|0^{A}\rangle\langle0^{A}|+|1^{A}\rangle\langle1^{A}|}{2}$ and thus the reduced state is mixed.

Comment: The notation makes it hard to read. Personally I prefer the more compact notation $\left|0^A\right>\otimes \left|0^B\right> \equiv \left|0^A0^B\right>$. Using this we see that $$2\rho^{AB} =\left|0^A 0^B\right>\left< 0^A 0^B\right| + \left|1^A 1^B \right>\left< 1^A 1^B \right| + \left|0^A 0^B\right>\left< 1^A 1^B\right| + \left|1^A 1^B \right>\left< 0^A 0^B\right|$$ 

Now when computing $\left<0^B\right|\rho^{AB}\left|0^B\right>$ the first term reduces to $\left|0^A\right>\left<0^A\right|$ and all the other terms vanish since the states $0^B$ and $1^B$ are orthogonal.

Comment: ...and similary when computing $\left<1^B\right|\rho^{AB}\left|1^B\right>$ we see that all but the second term in $\rho^{AB}$ gives a zero result again due to the states $0^B$ and $1^B$ being orthogonal.

Comment: @Winther it'd be very helpful if u could expand $\langle 0^{B}|\rho^{AB}|0^{B}\rangle$ and show that it becomes $|0^{A}\rangle \langle0^{A}|$. I am having trouble expanding it and eliminating the other 3 terms.

Comment: It's a lot to write so let me just comment on your derivation. The key thing missing in your derivation is to apply the orthogonality condition $\left<i^B\right|\left|\,j^B\right> = \delta_{ij}$ for $i,j\in\{0,1\}$. This will make most of your terms zero. There is also one big mistake in your computation when you apply $\left<0^B\right|\ldots \left|0^B\right>$. The $B$ state does not contract with the $A$ state so for example: $\left<0^B\right| \cdot \left|0^A\right>\otimes\left|0^B\right> = \left|0^A\right>\otimes\left<0^B\right|\left|0^B\right>$. You have contracted it with $A$ instead.

Comment: @Winther Thanx. So the only term survives in $\langle0^{B}|\rho^{AB}|0^{B}\rangle$ becomes $|0^{A}\rangle \otimes \langle0^{B}|0^{B}\rangle\langle0^{A}| \otimes \langle0^{B}|0^{B}\rangle=|0^{A}\rangle \otimes \langle0^{A}|\langle0^{B}|0^{B}\rangle \otimes \langle0^{B}|0^{B}\rangle\\=|0^{A}\rangle \otimes \langle0^{A}|1 \otimes 1=|0^{A}\rangle \otimes \langle0^{A}|$

Comment: Yes that looks correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\begin{split}
\langle0^{B}|\rho^{AB}|0^{B}\rangle=\frac{1}{2}\bigg(\langle0^{B}|\big[{|0^{A}\rangle \otimes|0^{B}\rangle\langle0^{A}|\otimes\langle0^{B}|+|1^{A}\rangle \otimes|1^{B}\rangle\langle0^{A}|\otimes\langle0^{B}|+|0^{A}\rangle \otimes|0^{B}\rangle\langle1^{A}|\otimes\langle1^{B}|+|1^{A}\rangle \otimes|1^{B}\rangle\langle1^{A}|\otimes\langle1^{B}|}\big]|0^{B}\rangle\Big)\\=\frac{1}{2}\Big({|0^{A}\rangle \otimes\langle0^{B}||0^{B}\rangle\langle0^{A}|\otimes\langle0^{B}||0^{B}\rangle+|1^{A}\rangle \otimes\langle0^{B}||1^{B}\rangle\langle0^{A}|\otimes\langle0^{B}||0^{B}\rangle+|0^{A}\rangle \otimes\langle0^{B}||0^{B}\rangle\langle1^{A}|\otimes\langle1^{B}||0^{B}\rangle+|1^{A}\rangle \otimes\langle0^{B}||1^{B}\rangle\langle1^{A}|\otimes\langle1^{B}||0^{B}\rangle}\Big)
\end{split}

Since $\langle1^{B}||0^{B}\rangle=0$ and $\langle0^{B}||0^{B}\rangle=\langle1^{B}||1^{B}\rangle=\mathcal{I}$

\begin{split}
\langle0^{B}|\rho^{AB}|0^{B}\rangle=\frac{1}{2}\Big(|0^{A}\rangle \otimes\mathcal{I}\langle0^{A}|\otimes\mathcal{I}\Big)=\frac{1}{2}\Big(|0^{A}\rangle \otimes\langle0^{A}|\Big)
\end{split}
Similarly,
\begin{split}
\langle1^{B}|\rho^{AB}|1^{B}\rangle=\frac{1}{2}\Big(|1^{A}\rangle \otimes\langle1^{A}|\Big)
\end{split}

The reduced density operator, $\rho^{A}=Tr_{B}(\rho^{AB})=\frac{|0^{A}\rangle \otimes\langle0^{A}|+|1^{A}\rangle \otimes\langle1^{A}|}{2}$